# Angular multi/select with async pipe

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable, multi-select, form-control

Here's an example of well implemented select and multiselect form controls using Angular Material:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search

The drawback is that they use hardcoded data (array).

How do I implement the same, but using async data (read from API, as Observable), not subscribing direcly to the values, but using `async` pipe in the view and showing progress indicator if needed?